# How to get status update history from Asana APIs

Tags: asana, asana-api

I would like to be able to access the history of status updates on a project in Asana.

I've tried getting this information from the "stories" endpoints, but they seemed to only focus on the task's history.

Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While past project updates are available in the Asana product, the API only supports current project status.  I will pass this request along to the API team.